# uwsgi + nginx + flask: upstream prematurely closed after file is downloaded

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04, uwsgi, flask

I created an endpoint on my flask which generates a spreadsheet from a database query (remote db) and then sends it as a download in the browser. Flask doesn't throw any errors. Uwsgi doesn't complain.

But when I check nginx's error.log I see a lot of

> 2014/12/10 05:06:24 [error] 14084#0: *239436 upstream prematurely
>   closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   34.34.34.34, server: me.com, request: "GET /download/export.csv HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://0.0.0.0:5002", host: "me.com", referrer:
>   "https://me.com/download/export.csv"

I deploy the uwsgi like

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5002 --buffer-size=32768 --module server --callab app
```

my nginx config:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     merge_slashes off;
     server_name me.com www.me.cpm;

     location / { try_files $uri @app; }
       location @app {
          include uwsgi_params;
          uwsgi_pass 0.0.0.0:5002;
          uwsgi_buffer_size 32k;
          uwsgi_buffers 8 32k;
          uwsgi_busy_buffers_size 32k;
     }

}

server {
      listen 443;
      merge_slashes off;
      server_name me.com www.me.com;

    location / { try_files $uri @app; }
       location @app {
          include uwsgi_params;
          uwsgi_pass 0.0.0.0:5002;
          uwsgi_buffer_size 32k;
          uwsgi_buffers 8 32k;
          uwsgi_busy_buffers_size 32k;
       }
}
```

Is this an nginx or uwsgi issue, or both?

Here's what uwsgi says on starting up

```
    *** Starting uWSGI 2.0 (64bit) on [Wed Dec 10 15:20:23 2014] *** compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 20 January 2014 16:57:53 os: Linux-3.8.0-29-generic #42~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 14 16:19:23 UTC 
2013 nodename: me.com machine: x86_64 clock source: unix detected number of CPU cores: 1 current 
working directory: /home/server.py detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi !!! no internal routing
 support, rebuild with pcre support !!! your processes number limit is 3781 your memory page size is 4096 bytes detected max file descriptor number: 1024 lock engine: pthread robust mutexes thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock) uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 0.0.0.0:5002 fd 3 Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:13:52)  [GCC 4.6.3] Python main interpreter initialized at 0x23632b0 python threads support enabled your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds mapped 202864 bytes (198 KB) for 1 cores
    *** Operational MODE: single process *** WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x23632b0 pid: 30636 (default app)
    *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
```

Here's what uwsgi says on downlaod request

> [pid: 30643|app: 0|req: 763/763] 33.33.33.33 () {56 vars in 2982
>   bytes} [Wed Dec 10 15:09:59 2014] GET /download/test.xlsx => generated
>   5564 bytes in 392 msecs via sendfile() (HTTP/1.1 200) 7 headers in 510
>   bytes (0 switches on core 0)

Comment: report uWSGI startup logs and request logs when doing the request

Comment: weird now it's not throwing the error anymore. I Don't know what changed.

Comment: @roberto I added those in the question

Comment: Your uWSGI log stops before the worker is loaded (unless you did not pasted it). Are you sure you are not calling app.run() in your entry point ?

Comment: I don't know it is no longer happening but wonder what was causing it.